# Entity Framework code first One to Many Relationship with same database table

Tags: .net, entity-framework, orm, ado.net

My Entities look like -

```
[Table("DoctorSchedule")]
    public class DoctorSchedule
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id {get; set;}

        [Column("DoctorId")]
        public virtual Doctor Doctor { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Schedule> Schedules { get; set; }
    }

public class Schedule
    {            
        public DayOfWeek Day { get; set; }
        public DateTime StartTime { get; set; }
        public DateTime EndTime { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public DoctorSchedule DoctorSchedule { get; set; }
    }
```

I would like to have entites as above but the SQL Table should be One. The Table should be "DoctorSchedule" with the columns are "Id","DoctorId","Day","StartTime","EndTime".

Please suggest the code using Data Annotations or FluentAPI.

Comment: So what should be the database counterpart of `ICollection<Schedule> Schedules`?

Comment: The DB counterpart for both DoctorSchedule and Schedule is same i.e the table named "DoctorSchedule". The entries would be like 1,11,6,9:00,11:00     2,11,6,3:00,4:00       3,11,6,4:30,5:30  and so forth...

Comment: But how would a `DoctorSchedule` know where to get its `Schedules`? There is no FK between them, so EF can't map the association. And giving each `DoctorSchedule` a `DoctorId` is not well normalized.

Comment: `DoctorSchedule` will contain master data of doctors and their visiting times (`Schedules`).Each row in that table will contain the following - PK (int/guid), DoctorId (Doctor Details in separate table), DayOfWeek, Start, End. Let me know if anything is wrong in this design. Feel free to propose alternate approach.

Comment: Two tables seems much simpler. Then `Schedule` can have an FK to `DoctorSchedule` so EF can easily establish the association.

Comment: Right..I ll either go with 2 table - 2 entity ( 1 to Many) or go ahead with just 1 entity- 1 table. Thanks for your suggestions...

Answer (score 0):

From the research it would appear that in order to have more than one entity per table, they need to inherit one another. I'm not sure if this will allow you to do what you want, but I tested it, and entity framework didn't complain, and the tables were successfully created. Again, this worked and allowed the models and relationships to be created, because I don't know what your needs are you'll have to test it yourself to see if it does what you need it to do. Best of luck!

You also appeared to want a Doctor entity, but provided no information about it, so I didn't attempt to do anything with a Doctor class.

```
public class DoctorSchedule
{

    public int DoctorSchedule_Id { get; set; }

    //[Column("DoctorId")] 
    //public virtual Doctor Doctor { get; set; } 
    public virtual ICollection<Schedule> Schedules { get; set; }
}

public class Schedule : DoctorSchedule
{
    public DayOfWeek Day { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartTime { get; set; }
    public DateTime EndTime { get; set; }

    public int Schedule_Id { get; set; }
    public int DoctorSchedule_FK { get; set; }


    public DoctorSchedule DoctorSchedule { get; set; }
}
```

Here's the DbContext/Fluent API I tried

```
public class DocContext : DbContext
{

    public DbSet<DoctorSchedule> DoctorSchedules { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Schedule> Schedules { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder mb)
    {

        //DoctorSchedule Mappings
        //
        mb.Entity<DoctorSchedule>()
            .ToTable("DoctorSchedule")
            .HasKey(ds => ds.DoctorSchedule_Id);

        mb.Entity<DoctorSchedule>()
            .Property(ds => ds.DoctorSchedule_Id)
            .HasColumnName("DoctorSchedule_Id")
            .HasColumnType("int")
            .IsRequired()
            .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None);

        mb.Entity<DoctorSchedule>()
            .HasMany(ds => ds.Schedules)
            .WithRequired(s => s.DoctorSchedule)
            .HasForeignKey(s => s.DoctorSchedule_FK);


        //Schedule Mappings
        //
        mb.Entity<Schedule>()
            .ToTable("DoctorSchedule")
            .HasKey(s => s.Schedule_Id); //It seems like a compound key is needed

        mb.Entity<Schedule>()
            .Property(ds => ds.Schedule_Id)
            .HasColumnName("Schedule_Id")
            .HasColumnType("int")
            .IsRequired()
            .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None);

        mb.Entity<Schedule>()
            .Property(s => s.Day)
            .HasColumnName("Day")
            .IsRequired()
            .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None);

        mb.Entity<Schedule>()
            .Property(s => s.StartTime)
            .HasColumnName("StartTime")
            .IsRequired()
            .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None);

        mb.Entity<Schedule>()
            .Property(s => s.EndTime)
            .HasColumnName("EndTime")
            .IsRequired()
            .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None);

        mb.Entity<Schedule>()
            .Property(ds => ds.DoctorSchedule_FK)
            .HasColumnName("DoctorSchedule_FK")
            .HasColumnType("int")
            .IsRequired()
            .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None);


}
```